# Swiping between tabs using createMaterialBottomTabNavigator for android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have used React Navigation's createMaterialBottomTabNavigator to create a bottom tab navigator in my app. I want the screens to "slide" in from the left or right when the tab is changed, and swiping on the screen to be able to change tabs. I've looked into the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html, and I can't find any configuration options that would make this happen. Why is this?

Comment: I *think* thats what the Transitioner is for but I've never used, worth taking a look though https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/transitioner.html

Comment: Transitioner works as a separate component, though, for building your own navigator. Why is there no configuration option built in for sliding animations in createMaterialBottomTabNavigator or createBottomTabNavigator like there is for createMaterialTopTabNavigator?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Solution

You can use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` instead of `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` and set the `tabBarPosition` option to bottom. [Official](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#docsNav)

## Why?

`swipeEnabled` is not supported anymore in BottomTabnavigator of React Navigation > 2.0.

> It is worth noting additionally that createBottomTabNavigator is different from the bottom tab navigator that is available through TabNavigator in that it does not support animationEnabled or swipeEnabled properties.

Check the [Release note](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/05/07/react-navigation-2.0.html#tab-navigator-split-into-separate-components).