# createMaterialTopTabNavigator with position bottom shifts up with keyboard

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am having difficulty in preventing my tabs from shifting up with the keyboard. I want the screens to "slide" in from the left or right when the tab is changed, and swiping on the screen to be able to change tabs and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197395/swiping-between-tabs-using-creatematerialbottomtabnavigator-for-android) so I used the `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` with `tabBarPosition: 'bottom'`. But the tab bar now moves up with the keyboard.

I also looked up on [transitioners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/transitioner.html) but I found it too complex for my understanding. Is there any easy alternative way to prevent the tabs from moving upward with the keyboard?

Answer (score -4):

check this page https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#bottomtabnavigatorconfig. Under the tabBarOptions look for keyboardHidesTabBar and implement it like this..

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  screen_1,
  screen_2
},{
  tabBarOptions:{
  keyboardHidesTabBar:true,
 }
})
```