# React Native enable swipe navigation on tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am using react-navigation and I am having an issue with it. I am trying to make it so the application changes tabs when a user swipes. However, I can't get it to work.

I have tried gestureEnabled and swipeEnabled keys but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

What am I doing wrong?

App:

```
const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Navigator>
        <>
          <Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name={'BottomTabsNavigator'} component={BottomTabsNavigator}/>
          {/* All other routes beside bottom Navigation ones go below */}
          <Screen options={{title: 'EditProfile'}} name="EditProfile" component={EditProfile} />
          <Screen options={{title: 'ChangePassword'}} name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
        </>
      </Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
);
```

BottomNavigator:

```
const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator();
export const BottomTabsNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Navigator>
      <Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Navigator>
  );
};
```

**Edit:**

Here is the issue with createMaterialBottomTabNavigator

- https://snack.expo.dev/_ESFgsWw3

Settings screen have to be scrolled all the way to the bottom

Answer (score 5):

gestureEnabled and swipeEnabled are not supported in @react-navigation/bottom-tabs

You can use createMaterialTopTabNavigator instead of createMaterialBottomTabNavigator and set the tabBarPosition option to bottom

reference from :-  [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53292932/19525620)

Comment: createMaterialTopTabNavigator has other issues though... if height of different screens are different it goes with the heigh of the biggest screen. Also the menu is not static on the screen... it is at the bottom of the screen no matter what

Comment: put the code here so we can check. it might be your styling.

Comment: Check here - https://snack.expo.dev/_ESFgsWw3.

for Settings screen... you have to scroll all the way to the bottom

Comment: i think it's working as expected. tab bar will always stay at the bottom.
https://snack.expo.dev/TxP4MCo1W

if you want to hide bottom tab or hide on scroll you can just use your custom tabs

<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
  {...}
</Tab.Navigator>

and in MytabBar you can return null (for no tab bar) or any view you want